# What does "We sure don't go undocumented" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can anyone help me to figure out this sentence's meaning?

> We're not restricted, but we sure don't go undocumented. May as well get a paycheck for it.

I was playing *Mass Effect 1* when I saw this sentence, and I've got no idea about this. The full of the conversation as follows:

> A: You've got a good grasp of the situation. You a career man?
>
> B: Yeah. A lot of biotics are. We're not restricted, but we sure don't go undocumented. May as well get a paycheck for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because to answer this, more knowledge about the Mass Effect universe is need. Better to ask this on [gaming.se]

Answer (score 1):

It means that even though they are free to act as they see fit, these "biotics" are  licensed ... OR ... someone is keeping a record of their activities, and they might as well be be compensated monetarily for whatever benefits their activities afford those who keep the records.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't go undocumented* is being used euphemistically. Meaning they are working legally.

**Undocumented**

> lacking necessary documents (as for e.g. permission to live or work in
>   a country)

([Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/undocumented))